# Can't invoke hello-world example script named ''test'' from PATH

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set up a hello world bash script. I have done the following:

```
cd
mkdir bin
touch bin/test
```

Then I opened `.bash_profile` in a text editor and added the following:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/my-user-name/bin"`

`bin/test` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'hello bash'
```

From the `/bin` directory, I run:

`test`

And get no output. I am expecting the output `hello bash`

I have tried running:

`chmod u+x test`

but not finding any change in output.

What I am missing here?

Comment: change the script's name to sth else, test is a builtin name

Comment: And make sure you put your script executable (`chmod`)

Answer (score -2):

`/usr/bin` is probably earlier in your path than the new directory you've added.  If you type `which test` it'll show which one is called when you type `test`.  Changing the command to `export PATH="/Users/my-user-name/bin:$PATH"` would mean that your directory is earlier and the `test` there would get used instead.

Comment: It would also break any other script that wants to use the original `/bin/test`.

Comment: `test` is typically a shell builtin, and those come before `PATH` is evaluated at all. (Yes, `test` goes through the parser like a regular command -- unlike `[[`, which is syntax -- but at execution time, the builtin is invoked in preference to the executable).

Comment: Indeed, a much better solution is to not call your program `test` {or `echo`, or `cd`, or `if`, or `function`, etc etc etc).

Comment: @AlexStiff, ...note that `which` doesn't know about builtins (or functions, or aliases, or hashed PATH lookups), which is why it's much better to use the `type` command instead. (And trying to point people to preexisting answers that have already been vetted for correctness &c. is why the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page in the Help Center advises against adding answers questions that "have already been asked many times before").

Comment: ...in this case, `type test` will emit *`test is a shell builtin`*; only if one runs `enable -n test` to disable that builtin will `type test` emit something like *`test is /usr/bin/test`*, at which point changing the PATH (as this answer advises) could work.